# how can i get a variable value into a select tag in html using php

Tags: php

so the line of code

```
    echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";
```

is where i am having a problem.  I am trying to get drop down menu to have the values of every name in the database.  here is my code, it is in a html file:

```
<select name = "author" id = "author">
                <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "user";
                    $password = "pass";
                    $database = "db";

                    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
                        if($con->connect_error){
                        die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error);
                    } 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                        /*echo <<<EOT 
<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"
EOT;*/
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
```

I have tried it using a normal string, and as an EOT.  Currently when i look at the html page it shows "$name" instead of the actual name.  I have done output testing and $name is storing what i expect it to store.

Comment: that's a bad design. what happens if you have two+ `John Smith` in your company? the `value` SHOULD be a primary key field value.

Comment: @Marc B Well i have a company of 15 people so i don't need to worry about that being an issue yet.  I'll look into it when the situation arises.

Comment: never say never. today's one-man-in-parents'-basement is next year's 5000 staff social media juggernaut, and the next-next-year's "what the heck happened" cover story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just take a step in the dark, You saved your file as HTML (.html) and not as a PHP file (.php)?

Comment: Yeah this is in an .html file but i put the "<?php ?>" tags so i could use php to access my database and put the values from the database into the drop down menu.

Comment: That is not possible, php only works with the php extention.

Comment: damn, im new to php.  so i should make a .php file and somehow call it from the html file? how can i use php in html?

Comment: You **can't** use php in side html but you **can** use html inside a php file. So just make a .php file and break out of the php `?>` after that, you can just go on with html. and when ever you want to go back to php just use `<?php`

Comment: @lazersquidsmcgee if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<option value = '".$name."'>".$name."</option>";
```

or

```
echo "<option value = '{$name}'>{$name}</option>";
```

Comment: neither of them worked. the first one got me
{$name} the second one got me ".$name."  When i output tested wether '$name' has the correct value i did it in another file so i think maybe $name does not have the same value as it did when i tested.  I can't figure out why it wouldn't be the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I remember there being something about PHP not processing variables between single quotes. The best way may be to break and concat the string

```
echo "<option value = '".$name."'>$name</option>";
```

Comment: You are correct that PHP will not recognize variables inside single quoted strings, but in the OP, the entire string is wrapped in double quotes. The embedded single quotes (for the HTML value attribute) shouldn't affect the variable parsing. In other words, the OP's code should be working and something else is at play here (based on the symptoms, PHPhil's answer is most likely correct).